# How to make a hole in a pygame surface?

Tags: pygame, pygame-surface, pygame2

I have 2 different images A and B, B is blit on top of A. I'd like to have (blit I guess) a hole in B that lets me see A through it.
Can anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can set make a hole in B before blitting it above A, using a color key (see https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_colorkey)

- pick a color K not used in B
- fill the "hole" in B with this color
- set the color key of B to K
- blit A
- blit B

Instead of a color key you also can use alpha transparency.

Comment: you have to fill it by this color

Comment: clear, thanks a lot.